# hard to tap buttons with xcode 9 and ios 11

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode9, uibuttonbaritem, ios11.2

I am facing a weird issue to tap UIButtons with Xcode 9 and IOS 11.2. The buttons are in a UIView and are simple call to action buttons such as submit and cancel.

When I click on these buttons, the *action is triggered* only when I click to the left most part of the button. I have checked that the view width is enough to allow the button to be inclusive in it as a whole. However, for some reason, I am not able to see why I am not able to click the button. A similar problem is encountered in other views too.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used Xcode's view debugger to check whether anything clips your buttons at run time?

Comment: @PhillipMills. Thanks for the prompt response. I checked but don't see any overlapping view that would block it from triggering. Did you also face a similar problem?

Comment: Can you post some details of how it is all setup.  Perhaps some code you are using and/or screenshots of the layout.  It's difficult to tell what is wrong otherwise as it could be any number of things.

Comment: `view width is enough`, can you confirm by giving border to this view & make sure buttons are inside this view? this happens usually when buttons goes out of view... also can you post screenshot of the xcode to check the view & inner elements hierarchy?